# Android - Do something while touching the screen

Tags: java, android, touch

There is an extended SurficeView class that I want that while the user is touching the screen (like onKeyDown) it does something.

Like this:

```
@Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        Log.e("Touching", "Touching the Screen");
        return true;
    }
```

While the user is touching the screen I want my LogCat to be spammed (just testing) 'til I'm not touching it but it only shows the message twice: when I touch and when I release.

Answer (score 1):

Here is Different Behavour of OnTouch Listener

```
setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                Log.d(TAG, "mode=DRAG");
                switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    Log.i("Tag", "1");

                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
                    Log.i("Tag", "2");

                    break;// return  
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    Log.i("Tag", "3");

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
                    Log.i("Tag", "4");


                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    Log.i("Tag", "5");
                    break;
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

write Log in one of below actions like:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
   if(event.getAction==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
    Log.e("Touching", "Touching the Screen");
  }
    else if(event.getAction==MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
    Log.e("Touching up", "Touching the Screen up");}
    return true;
}
```